# AngularJS objects in an array to new one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

```
DashboardService.GetDateList($scope.datestart, $scope.dateend).then(function (response) {
    $scope.listdate = response.data;
});
```

i get an array list from this function above

```
[{"day":1,"sql_date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00"},
{"day":2,"sql_date":"2017-04-02T00:00:00"},
{"day":3,"sql_date":"2017-04-03T00:00:00"},
{"day":4,"sql_date":"2017-04-04T00:00:00"},
{"day":5,"sql_date":"2017-04-05T00:00:00"}
```

how can i push all day value from this array into a new one.

Comment: did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` to get the `value` of every `day` key.

```js
var arr = [{"day":1,"sql_date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00"},{"day":2,"sql_date":"2017-04-02T00:00:00"},{"day":3,"sql_date":"2017-04-03T00:00:00"},{"day":4,"sql_date":"2017-04-04T00:00:00"},{"day":5,"sql_date":"2017-04-05T00:00:00"}],
    newArr = arr.map(v => v.day);
    
    console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: DashboardService.GetDateList($scope.datestart, $scope.dateend).then(function (response) {
    $scope.listdate = response.data;
}); => JSON

Comment: i try this one but all value i get is [object Object]

Comment: `DashboardService.GetDateList($scope.datestart, $scope.dateend).then(function (response) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                String(response.data[i]);
                console.log(String(response.data[i]));
            }
        });`

Comment: @NguyenQuocDat Did you fix it?

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

#### You can achieve this in different ways :

1. Using JavaScript [**for...in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

   **DEMO**

```js
var responseObj = [{"day":1,"sql_date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00"},
{"day":2,"sql_date":"2017-04-02T00:00:00"},
{"day":3,"sql_date":"2017-04-03T00:00:00"},
{"day":4,"sql_date":"2017-04-04T00:00:00"},
{"day":5,"sql_date":"2017-04-05T00:00:00"}];

var newArr = [];

for (var i in responseObj) {
    newArr.push({"day":responseObj[i].day});  
}

console.log(newArr);
```

2. Using [**Array map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

   **DEMO**

```js
var responseObj = [{"day":1,"sql_date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00"},
{"day":2,"sql_date":"2017-04-02T00:00:00"},
{"day":3,"sql_date":"2017-04-03T00:00:00"},
{"day":4,"sql_date":"2017-04-04T00:00:00"},
{"day":5,"sql_date":"2017-04-05T00:00:00"}];

var newArr = responseObj.map(function(item) {
  return {"day":item.day};
});

console.log(newArr);
```

3. Using JavaScript [**for**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop.

   **DEMO**

```js
var responseObj = [{"day":1,"sql_date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00"},
{"day":2,"sql_date":"2017-04-02T00:00:00"},
{"day":3,"sql_date":"2017-04-03T00:00:00"},
{"day":4,"sql_date":"2017-04-04T00:00:00"},
{"day":5,"sql_date":"2017-04-05T00:00:00"}];

var newArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < responseObj.length; i++) {
  newArr.push({"day": responseObj[i].day});
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Still you can use map instead of for loop. Please find the code snippet below

```
var arr = [{"day":1,"sql_date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00"},{"day":2,"sql_date":"2017-04-02T00:00:00"},{"day":3,"sql_date":"2017-04-03T00:00:00"},{"day":4,"sql_date":"2017-04-04T00:00:00"},{"day":5,"sql_date":"2017-04-05T00:00:00"}],
newArr = arr.map(function(obj) { return obj.day });

console.log(newArr);
```